# Intellij throwing error newly created demon process has a different context than expected. java home is different

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I am working on a Java project on IntelliJ. Gradle sync throws the error: newly created demon process has a different context than expected: Java home is different.

Error message contains also a link "Open JDK Settings". On clicking that it opens android SDK settings though it is not an android project.

In addition I got the following error in logs:

> --- expecting "JDK_PATH_I_HAVE_CONFIGURED" but was '/afs/.@mount....'

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Zulu JDK? There is known problem that Gradle has this error with some Zulu JDKs instaled via SDKMAN. See related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/12840 Using different JDK or install it not via SDKMAN should help.